# the_post_thumbnail(); only works with fullsize images

Tags: php

The author of the theme, im using,
used "the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120));" to define the thumbnail size.

but for some reason, it only works with small banners (300x84), but i need those banners to be bigger in height.
And than, the theme uses the full size picture in a thumbnail area of (68x165)
And if i use smaller banners, the pixels would be visible.

This is my first WP project and im not familiar where all the stuff is, that i need to fix this problem.

also: no plugins installed. (except 'regenerate-thumbnails', but i installed it, to see, if it can fix that problem. Didn't work, otherwise i woudn't waste your time with that question.)-> Some other posts wrote, that this plugin could solve this problem. But not in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell WP to generate this image sizes at first...

Use function `add_image_size` and then "regenerate the thumbnails":

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180, true ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, hard crop mode
```

Note "custom-size" string which could be anything you want.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

After that you can use the `the_post_thumbnail` function with our custom defined image size "custom-size":

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

More resources:

- http://wpshout.com/adding-using-custom-image-sizes-wordpress-guide-best-thing-ever/
- http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-custom-image-sizes-in-your-theme-and-resizing-existing-images-to-the-new-sizes--wp-24815

Comment: Thank you. But it didn't completely. I was only able to import other sizes, but not crop them as i want. So i just deleted "the_post_thumbnail(array(120,120));" from the php-file and now guess what happend? Yes. Problem solved. The images are now in the correct size. But thank you anyway for the URLs. Maybe i need them later again.